# How to make the UIKeyboard black?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikeyboard

I've seen this SO question here: [Can I tint (black) a UIKeyboard? If so, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202817/can-i-tint-black-a-uikeyboard-if-so-how), where the top answer suggests that you can hack around but doing so may get your app rejected by Apple. This must not be true, as I've seen other iPhone applications (a major one being Clear) that have a black UIKeyboard. How is it done?

Here's a screenshot of Clear for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this out

```
   [(UITextField *)mySubView setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
```

or just adding `setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert` appropriately depending on how you have this set up!

Answer (score 4):

Isnt this the `[textView setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];` style?
Otherwise, as stated. It's not possible without hacking the subviews. Of course you can still setup your own complete inputView.

Answer (score 3):

Starting in iOS 7, you can use `UIKeyboardAppearanceDark`

So, for example:

```
self.textField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark
```