# iOS7 Keyboard Return/Done/Search tint colour

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uikeyboard

With the new iOS7 UIView tint color it becomes pretty easy to theme an entire app quickly. It even changes the color of the text caret when editing UITextFields.

However, the keyboard's bottom right 'dismiss' button (can be Done, Search, etc) is always blue. Is there any way to change this? It would look really nice if it matched the tint color of the rest of the app.

[image: iOS7 UISearchBar keyboard]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With a little hack maybe you can achieve the effect you are looking for. But it might not be able to pass the app review.

```
-(NSArray*)subviewsOfView:(UIView*)view withType:(NSString*)type{
    NSString *prefix = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@",type];
    NSMutableArray *subviewArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        NSArray *tempArray = [self subviewsOfView:subview withType:type];
        for (UIView *view in tempArray) {
            [subviewArray addObject:view];
        }
    }
    if ([[view description]hasPrefix:prefix]) {
        [subviewArray addObject:view];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:subviewArray];
}

-(void)addColorToUIKeyboardButton{
    for (UIWindow *keyboardWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        for (UIView *keyboard in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {
            for (UIView *view in [self subviewsOfView:keyboard withType:@"UIKBKeyplaneView"]) {
                UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[(UIView *)[[self subviewsOfView:keyboard withType:@"UIKBKeyView"] lastObject] frame]];
                newView.frame = CGRectMake(newView.frame.origin.x + 2, newView.frame.origin.y + 1, newView.frame.size.width - 4, newView.frame.size.height -3);
                [newView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
                newView.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
                [view insertSubview:newView belowSubview:((UIView *)[[self subviewsOfView:keyboard withType:@"UIKBKeyView"] lastObject])];

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The app I used to decode the view hierarchy was : http://revealapp.com/

The end result is like this: [image: Green Key]

Comment: Hah, I downloaded and tested out Reveal just after I asked this question, to experiment with exactly what you did above. Anyone tried this on a published app yet? Any feedback on the review process?

Comment: I think it would probably fail the review. See this question here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202817/can-i-tint-black-a-uikeyboard-if-so-how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202817/can-i-tint-black-a-uikeyboard-if-so-how) Alternatively you can try to put a colored view behind the keyboard to generally color it.

Comment: Also I would really be glad if you can vote my answer up. I'm new to SO and im really running low on rep, preventing me from posting direct images, voting up etc. Thanks

Comment: No probs, done. Note for future ref I would have upvoted straight away if you had of answered the question fully. Basically your answer was only half the solution (finding the 'Done/Search' key UIView). The overlay you add doesn't really match the key. I found the same thing through Reveal. The main prob with this approach is the private class UIKBKeyView draws the entire thing, and doesn't seem to expose any way to change the back color. To be a complete answer I would expect it to include code that changes the key color matching the current bounds of the key.

Comment: Still, your answer is better than the other one talking about dark/light keyboards, so thanks!  (not sure who upvoted that one, it wasnt me).

Comment: Adding a colored view in the back of the key act like a tint. with soem trial and error you could draw a rounded rectangle to match the shape of the button. But i believe it should be a gray button instead of a blue one to have the look. Thank you for the upvote!

Comment: I've just went ahead and improved the answer.

Comment: Nice stuff! Did that keyboard have a gray button to start with? Or blue? Without an official API, this can definitely be marked as the accepted answer now.

Comment: It had a gray button. With a blue button it wouldn't have the desired color. Cheers

Comment: is anyone able to pass the review with a custom colored done button?

Comment: Can you please share this swift version

Answer (score 3):

You can not change button tint color but you can set `keyboard` Tint color by using  `UIKeyboardAppearance`

[image]

**Example**: `yourTextField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;`

Here is a very nice document provided by Apple, take a look here:

[Managing the Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I am already aware of the dark/light keyboards. My question was specifically about the 'dismiss' button on the keyboard. It seems to match apple's default iOS7 tint color, so was hoping it was also able to be changed - doesn't look like it though.

Comment: You certainly can change the tint color of Keyboard window. It's not documented and you'd have to find it in view hierarchy. It's a very lightweight patch I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

```
let colors: [UIColor] = [.red, .blue, .green, .purple, .yellow, .orange, .brown]

if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { 
    $0.isType(string: "UIRemoteKeyboardWindow") 
}) {
    if let keyplaneView = window.subview(ofType: "UIKBKeyplaneView") {
        for (i, keyView) in keyplaneView.subviews.filter({
            $0.isType(string: "UIKBKeyView") 
        }).enumerated() {
            let view = UIView(frame: keyView.bounds)
            view.backgroundColor = colors[i].withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            keyView.addSubview(view)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a color map of the keys in the `UIKBKeyplaneView`:

[image]