# Can the color of Search/Go button of iphone keyboard be changed ?

Tags: iphone, ios7

**Can the color of the default Go button in ios7 keyboard be changed ?**

[image]

Comment: Hei, Jayanath!

I guess this answer can be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465765/ios7-keyboard-return-done-search-tint-colour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Never. Create your own keyboard - it's the only way out of this.